# where to publish office 2013 App content files

Tags: office-2013, office-app

I have developed an App for office 2013 using NAPA. Now i want to publish it to office store. There is too much links to that and I'm confused between them.

On the NAPA left pane, there is button to publish the app. It then asked me to enter URL of the server that 'll host my app. My question do i have to buy a server to host my files or what?.

Answer (score 0):

There is a "Publish" button on the left. This generates an app package and puts it on a SharePoint Library, from there, you can download it and submit it to the store. Not sure why there is an intermediate step of putting it on a library first, it should just spit out the package IMO.

Answer (score 0):

yes, the app needs to be hosted on a webserver. MS does not host your app for you.
The App in the office store is purely a reference that enables users to find your app